# How do I toggle/change between colors every time the mouse is clicked?[JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

So I made the originally pink rectangle turn into orange when the mouse is clicked

```
 public void start(Stage frame) throws Exception {

    final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();


    rectangle.setX(50);
    rectangle.setY(50);
    rectangle.setWidth(100);
    rectangle.setHeight(50);
    rectangle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    rectangle.setFill(Color.PINK);

    Pane pane = new Pane();

    pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 200, 200);

    frame.setScene(scene);
    frame.show();

    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler <MouseEvent>(){
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouse) {
            rectangle.setFill(Color.ORANGE);

            }

    });





}
```

What I want to do is I want it to toggle between these two color(pink & orange) each time I click.

> I do not want to use getClickCount() method because I couldn't get it to pink color again in one click instead of two clicks.

I also wanted it to change in a set of colors each time I click in sequence.

I am out of idea on how to it. I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pink-orange just toggle the color based on the current color:

```
rect.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    Color curFill = rect.getFill();
    if (Color.ORANGE.equals(curFill) {
        rect.setColor(Color.PINK);
    } else if (Color.PINK.equals(curFill)) {
        rect.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    } else {
        // Shouldn't end up here if colors stay either Pink or Orange
    }
});
```

If you want an arbitrary number of colors to switch between in sequence, put the colors into an `Array` or `List` and keep track of the current index:

```
Color[] colors = new Color[size]; // class variable - fill with appropriate colors
int curIndex = 0; // class variable

rect.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
    curIndex = curIndex >= colors.length - 1 ? 0 : curIndex + 1;
    rect.setFill(colors[curIndex]);
});
```

Note: I used Java 8 Lambdas for the `EventHandler`s, but you can always use anonymous classes like you did in the code you posted.

Comment: Works pretty great!! Much obliged